# Лишний вывод else

Tags: python, python-3.x, if

В переменную `a` ввожу серийник, дальше в `C:/Python3/1.txt` хранится список айпишников серверов, к этим сервакам коннектится paramiko. Скрипт делает `cat` на каждом серваке и сохраняет всё в файлы.
Потом то, что я ввёл в переменной `a` ищется в сохранённых файлах `addr_{info["hostname"]}.txt` и если есть значение `a` выводится, это всё работает.
Но при любом условии у меня все выводится еще `else` как бы и куда я `else` не ставил, либо перестаёт работать поиск, либо поиск работает но всегда выводится этот else.

```
import paramiko

a = input('введите: ')

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy)
file1 = open('C:/Python3/1.txt', 'r')
for line in file1:

    info = {}
    info['ip'], info['hostname'], *_ = line.split()

    def connector():
        client.connect(info['ip'], username='test', port=22, key_filename='C:/Python3')

    try:
        connector()
        stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('cat /etc/1/test.txt')
        data = stdout.read() + stderr.read()


        with open(f'C:/Python3/addr_{info["hostname"]}.txt', 'wb') as f:
            f.write(data)

    except Exception as e:
        error_log = str(e)
        print('error_log')

    with open(f'C:/Python3/addr_{info["hostname"]}.txt', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        for line in file:

            if a in line:
                print(info['hostname'] + ' - ' + line, end='')
else:
    print('не найдено')
exit()
```

Как добиться того что бы `else` выводился только в том случае, когда `if a in line:` ничего не находил.

Comment: Сори, я ничего не понял. Что значит "выводится `else`"?

Comment: Поставить индентацию правильно может?

Comment: @Alexey Leshchenko применяется else, выводится его принт

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас блок `else` связан с `for`. При таком связывании код из `else` будет выполняться, если выход из `for` произошёл без `break` (в Вашем случае — всегда).

Удаление блока `else` не повлияет на алгоритм:

```py
for line in file1:
    ...
#  else:
#      print('не найдено')
```

---

**UPD:**

Чтобы один раз вывести `не найдено`, если подстроки нет в файле, можно завести флаг. Например, `is_find`:

```py
is_find = False
for line in file:
    if a in line:
        print(info['hostname'] + ' - ' + line, end='')
        is_find = True
if not is_find:
    print('не найдено')
```

Comment: Ну так надо его поставить под `if a in line:`, насколько я понимаю. Возможно, это ошибка индентации при вставке кода в вопрос

Comment: @nomnoms12 да, конечно, удаление не повлияет, и если действительно удалить будет всё ок. НО хотелось бы, если ничего не найдено, всё таки отрабатывал else

Comment: @sakhalin Тогда переместите этот блок под `if a in line:` как Вам посоветовали Выше.

Comment: @dIm0n если else ставлю под if, (у меня не один файл с результатом а 6 файлов) else будет отрабатывать по каждому файлу и выводе у меня будет по каждому файлу 6 строк не найдено

Comment: @sakhalin *Как добиться того что бы else выводился только в том случае, когда `if a in line:` ничего не находил.* - у вас это в вопросе написано. Если вы, соответственно, поставите `else` под этим if-ом, то получите нужное поведение

Comment: @dIm0n Да если `if a in line:` не существует, `else` будет работать, но выводить будет 6 строк по кол-ву файлов, а хочу только одну строку. Может не корректно задал вопрос....

Comment: @dIm0n но ко всему этому, даже если `if a in line:` существует, в моём примере всё равно отработает `else` и выведет вместе с найденными строками `не найдено`

Comment: @sakhalin Вы можете завести флаг, чтобы выводить только одну строку. Я обновил ответ, попробуйте.

Comment: @nomnoms12 Ваш пример работает всё ок) Действительно если не существует `if a in line:` то теперь вместо 6 строк только одна, так как надо. Но появился другой вопрос, возможно не относящийся к этой теме. Теперь если `if a in line:` существует, то к выводу всё равно добавляется `не найдено`